# Three.js, calculate sphere from polar coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, trigonometry

I am using `three.js` to calculate a sphere. I am using two `for` loops, one for theta and one for phi, and then I am transforming the polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. For every calculated point I add a `Point`. The result is not a sphere.

This is the nested `for` loop:

```
const distance = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < 360; i += 10) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 360; j += 10) {
    let theta = i * (Math.PI / 180);
    let phi = j * (Math.PI / 180);
    let x = Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi) * distance;
    let y = Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi) * distance;
    let z = distance * Math.sin(phi);
    const lightSphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    lightSphere.position.set(x, y, z);
    scn.add(lightSphere);
  }
}
```

And here is the full code, including the result: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-alex-5xr6k?file=/src/Test.jsx:742-1256)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

j must be in range [-90, 90] 9instead of [0, 260]. Notice that you are creating slices (360 °) from the South Pole to the North Pole (180 °).

You must compute the `sin(theta)` and the `cos(theta)` and multiply both with `cos(phi)`:

<s>`let x = Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi) * distance;`</s>
<s>`let y = Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi) * distance;`</s>

```js
let x = Math.cos(theta) * Math.cos(phi) * distance;
let y = Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi) * distance;
```

Complete algorithm:

```js
const distance = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < 360; i += 10) {
    for (let j = -90; j < 90; j += 10) {
        let theta = i * (Math.PI / 180);
        let phi = j * (Math.PI / 180);
        let x = Math.cos(theta) * Math.cos(phi) * distance;
        let y = Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi) * distance;
        let z = distance * Math.sin(phi);
        const lightSphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
        lightSphere.position.set(x, y, z);
        scn.add(lightSphere);
   }
}
```

[image]

You create circles (slices) using [Polar coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) (`distance`, `theta`). The [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) can be get by:

```
xc = cos(theta) * distance
yc = sin(theta) * distance
```

Finally you do something similar for the sphere:

```
x = xc * cos(phi)
y = yc * cos(phi)
z = sin(phi) * distance
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine. But I don't really understand the theory behind. Do you know a get resource where it explained in detail? Why you replaced sin with cos? I used the formula from wikipedia to convert from polar to Cartesian coordinates

Comment: @otto It is just geometry. You create circles (slices) using [Polar coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) (`distance`, `theta`). The [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) can be get by _xc = cos(theta) * distance_, _yc = sin(theta) * distance_ and for the sphere _x = xc * cos(phi)_, _y = yc * cos(phi)_, _z = sin(phi) * distance_